# Nuxtjs fails to load data from Express Backend running on different port

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, nuxt.js

My NUXT SSR website https://tejasjadhav2001.tech is hosted at https://34.93.29.137:3333 and Expressjs server for REST backend is hosted at https://34.93.29.137:3000

https://34.93.29.137:3333 is proxied to the Nginx root which uses tejasjadhav2001.tech as the domain

The frontend calls the backend rest API like this:

FRONTEND:

```
getArticles(id) {
    return axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: https://34.93.29.137:3000/api/v1/blog/`,
      withCredentials: true,
});
```

But the request to the backend is failing with the CORS error

Even though I have configured CORS on the backend like this:

BACKEND:

```
const corsOptions ={
    origin:[
            'https://34.93.29.137:3000/',
            'https://34.93.29.137:3333',
            'https://34.93.29.137',
            'https://tejasjadhav2001.tech',
            'http://tejasjadhav2001.tech',
    ],
    credentials:true,            //access-control-allow-credentials:true
    optionSuccessStatus:200
}
console.log("Using cors options");
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

**But the catch here is this CORS issue is not seen when I call the Backend API manually via the browser for example: https://34.93.29.137:3000/api/v1/blog , accepts the SSL warning, it loads the data and now if I go to https://34.93.29.137:3333 or https://tejasjadhav2001.tech, it also loads the data from Backend and site works all fine after**

Attaching my NGINX config too

```
a@instance-1:~$ cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/default 
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name tejasjadhav2001.tech www.tejasjadhav2001.tech;

        gzip on;
        gzip_types  text/plain application/xml;
        gzip_proxied    no-cache no-store private expired auth;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/tejasjadhav2001.tech/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/tejasjadhav2001.tech/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    #ssl_password_file /etc/ssl/certs/pass.pass;
        ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        # This is a cache for SSL connections
        ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout 1440m;

        rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;


        location / {
                proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_redirect          off;
                proxy_buffering         on;
                #proxy_cache             STATIC;
                proxy_cache_valid   200 1d;
                proxy_cache_use_stale   error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;

                proxy_pass              https://34.93.29.137:3333;
                proxy_read_timeout  1m;
                proxy_connect_timeout   1m;
        }
```

Is this issue with the CORS or SSL cert?
Thanks,
Tejas

Comment: Nuxt might run the first query on the server initially and not face any CORS issue, hence why you're bypassing it initially maybe? Also, drop a quick SSL on it just to be sure with Let's Encrypt or your host.

Comment: SSL cert is added. pls check nginx conf.


 If you manually visit: https://34.93.29.137:3000/api/v1/blog accept the SSL warning and then visit or reload tejasjadhav2001.tech it works fine 

Can you please help me, I am really confused

Comment: _the CORS error_? What CORS error?

Comment: @jub0bs There was issue with SSL on Backend, solved after adding SSL on backend

Answer (score 1):

The browser console shows this error  `GET https://34.93.29.137:3000/api/v1/blog/?page=1&limit=10&sort=-dateCreated net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`. It's possibly SSL cert error. Please try to configure the backend to use proper SSL cert.

Comment: ssl cert is added in NGINX config
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/tejasjadhav2001.tech/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/tejasjadhav2001.tech/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot


If you manually visit: https://34.93.29.137:3000/api/v1/blog/?page=1&limit=10&sort=-dateCreated (accept SSL warrning) and then visit or reload https://tejasjadhav2001.tech/ it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue: The issue was with the Backend SSL cert, After I added SSL to my expressjs server, it solved the issue

Below diffs solved the issue:

```
-const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
+var options = {
+       key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/privkey.pem'),
+       cert:fs.readFileSync('./ssl/fullchain.pem')
+};
+const server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(process.env.PORT, '0.0.0.0',() => {
        console.log("port is ", process.env.PORT);
 });
```

and adding ['https://tejasjadhav2001.tech:3000/'] in `corsOptions.origin`

SSL certs  are generated with letsencrypt:

```
a@instance-1:~/Desktop/demo-digoc-app-service$ ls -lrt ./ssl/
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 a    a    1436 Nov 26 12:00 certificate.pem
-rw------- 1 a    a    1704 Nov 26 12:01 privatekey.pem
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5563 Nov 29 06:28 fullchain.pem
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1704 Nov 29 06:30 privkey.pem
a@instance-1:~/Desktop/demo-digoc-app-service$
```